# How do I implement 301 redirects from a parameter to prevent Google from continuing to index that content?

Tags: 301-redirect

I need to implement 301 redirection for

- `example.com/?id=113742`
- `example.com/?id=154242`
- `example.com/?id=XXXXXX`

All those sites to example.com. I need it in htaccess. I`m using wordpress 
How do I do that?

Comment: What do you want to redirect to?

Comment: Please edit your question to include additional details as requested so that we can re-open this and and answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but you still don't say where you want the redirects to go